# Can I intercept/trap object behavior on comparison for equality

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

Playing around with Javascript objects is fun, and annoying:

```
const MyObject = function(value)  {
  let _myObject = {
    [Symbol.valueOf]() {
      return value
    },
    [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
      return value
    },
  }
  return _myObject
}

let o = new MyObject("a")
let p = new MyObject("b")

o == "a"
# true

p == "a"
# false

o < p
# true

p < o
# false

p + "-foo"
# 'p-foo'
```

Having custom objects behave like primitive types looks potentially useful and intuitive! Until you try something like this:

```
let o = new MyObject("a")
let p = new MyObject("a")

o == "a"
# true

p == "a"
# true

o == p
# false
```

Javascript will (quite sensibly) return `false` when comparing two objects for equality.

Would there be any way to hack around the apparent “inconsistency” arising in a case like this? (Maybe some clever usage of [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)/[Proxy handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy#handler_functions)? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I intercept/trap object behavior on comparison for equality

No, you can't. The behavior of `==` is governed by the [IsLooselyEqual](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-islooselyequal) abstract operation in the specification, which just hands off to [`IsStrictlyEqual`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-isstrictlyequal) when the operands both have the same type (and all objects are considered the same type in JavaScript). With the IsStrictlyEqual operation (`===`), when both of the operands are objects, the result is based entirely on whether they're the *same* object. There's no trap in there that you can hook into, not even with a Proxy.